# How to know if the fo:block is at the beginning of the page

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I'm facing a problem where I need to display information in the header and sporadically in the body. However if the information happens to be the first line of a page, I don't want to display it. I know that this question is really weird, but is there a way to achieve it with xslt 1.0 ?

Comment: Do you want to not display the header if the information is in the first line of the page?

Comment: @TonyGraham Yes, that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the information happens to be the first line of a page, I don't want to display it. [... Is] there a way to achieve it with xslt 1.0 ?

Pagination is performed by the XSL-FO processor as part of formatting.  In a standard XSL workflow, formatting occurs after XSLT transformation of the source document.  In general, therefore, it is not known at the XSLT stage whether a particular block will appear at the top of a page (or spanning pages).  The XSLT result cannot depend on that information unless it has some way to predict it, which would depend on details of the input document and transformation and presentation medium.